# How to properly remove graph from Tkinter frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have several graphs that I want to display on a button press. To do that, I make the `plt.Figure` and `FigureCanvasTkAgg` variables global, and just erase the axis each time on button press with `ax.clear()`. After that, i added a feature using `Figure.canvas.mpl_connect`: when I press on the graph area, the second point is highlighted with a vertical line. When I print some simple output (in my case, `print('Vertical Line Constructed')` in the `select_trade_with_mouse` function), it turns out that the event is created for each graph that was constructed and erased: when I generate a graph and press on graph (that generates event), then the `print('Vertical Line Constructed')` is executed just once. If I generate the second graph and click on graph, then the `print('Vertical Line Constructed')` is executed twice. Looks like the old graphs aren't destroyed, and the click on graph generates an event for each graph in memory, even if it is not displayed. I tried `plt.cla()`, `plt.clf()` and `plt.close()`, but none of them completely removes the graph.

My question is, how can I properly remove the old graphs? So that a click on graph will generate only one event?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


def select_trade_with_mouse(event, ax, graph, data):
    global vertical_line_trading
    print('Vertical Line Constructed')
    if vertical_line_trading:
        vertical_line_trading.remove()
        del vertical_line_trading
    vertical_line_trading = ax.axvline(data, color='b')
    graph.draw()

def construct_graph(change_by = 0):  
    global data
    global graph_index
    print('Graph Constructed')
    graph_index = graph_index + change_by
    ax.clear()
    #plt.close('all')
    line = data[graph_index].plot(x='x', y='y', linestyle='-', ax=ax, linewidth=1, color='y')
    click_id = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: select_trade_with_mouse(event, ax, graph, data[graph_index].loc[1, 'x']))    
    graph.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    vertical_line_trading = None
    graph_index = 0

    ## Some random data
    data = []
    for i in range(10):
        data.append(pd.DataFrame({'x': [1+i, 2+i, 3+2*i], 'y': [1+2*i, 2+i, 3+i]}))

    root = tk.Tk()
    main_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=600, width=1200)
    graph_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, height=500, width=1200)

    ## Graph
    figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=100)
    ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graph_frame)
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    ## Buttons to switch between graphs
    prev_graph_button = tk.Button(graph_frame, command = lambda: construct_graph(-1), height=10, width=10, text='Prev\nGraph')
    next_graph_button = tk.Button(graph_frame, command = lambda: construct_graph(1), height=10, width=10, text='Next\nGraph')
    prev_graph_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    next_graph_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    for frame in [main_frame, graph_frame]:
        frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill='both')
        frame.pack_propagate(0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to remove graph. You have to use `mpl_connect()` only once at start, and not again and again when you clear graph.

Or you have to keep `click_id` in global variable and use `mpl_disconnect(click_id)` before `click_id = mpl_connect()`

I create global variable `click_id = None` at start and later in `construct_graph()` I remove previous `click_id` if it is not `None`. This way graph has assigned only one function

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


def select_trade_with_mouse(event, ax, graph, data):
    global vertical_line_trading
    print('Vertical Line Constructed')
    if vertical_line_trading:
        vertical_line_trading.remove()
        del vertical_line_trading
    vertical_line_trading = ax.axvline(data, color='b')
    graph.draw()

def construct_graph(change_by = 0):  
    global data
    global graph_index
    global click_id 

    print('Graph Constructed')
    graph_index = graph_index + change_by
    ax.clear()
    #plt.close('all')
    line = data[graph_index].plot(x='x', y='y', linestyle='-', ax=ax, linewidth=1, color='y')

    # if function exist then remove it
    if click_id: # if click_id is not None:
        figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(click_id)

    click_id = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: select_trade_with_mouse(event, ax, graph, data[graph_index].loc[1, 'x']))   

    graph.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    click_id = None # create global varaible with default value at start

    vertical_line_trading = None
    graph_index = 0

    ## Some random data
    data = []
    for i in range(10):
        data.append(pd.DataFrame({'x': [1+i, 2+i, 3+2*i], 'y': [1+2*i, 2+i, 3+i]}))

    root = tk.Tk()
    main_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=600, width=1200)
    graph_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, height=500, width=1200)

    ## Graph
    figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=100)
    ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graph_frame)
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    ## Buttons to switch between graphs
    prev_graph_button = tk.Button(graph_frame, command = lambda: construct_graph(-1), height=10, width=10, text='Prev\nGraph')
    next_graph_button = tk.Button(graph_frame, command = lambda: construct_graph(1), height=10, width=10, text='Next\nGraph')
    prev_graph_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    next_graph_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    for frame in [main_frame, graph_frame]:
        frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill='both')
        frame.pack_propagate(0)

    root.mainloop()
```